# Self Size Custom View from xib in Stack view in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, uistackview

I'm new at Xamarin development and I'm trying to display the list of comments for a specific ticket. The comments' body have different text size. I have a custom view TicketCommentRowUIView.xib:

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;
using ObjCRuntime;

namespace Project.iOS
{
    public partial class TicketCommentRowUIView : UIView
    {
        public TicketCommentRowUIView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }
        public static TicketCommentRowUIView CreateView(TicketCommentModel model)
        {
            TicketCommentRowUIView v = CreateView();
            v.LoadModelInfo(model);

            return v;
        }
        private static TicketCommentRowUIView CreateView()
        {
            var arr = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("TicketCommentRowUIView", null, null);
            var v = Runtime.GetNSObject<TicketCommentRowUIView>(arr.ValueAt(0));

            return v;
        }

        private void LoadModelInfo(TicketCommentModel model)
        {
            DateReply.Text = model.CreatedAt.ToShortDateString();
            MessageReply.Text = model.Content;
            ReplierImage.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("default_image_user");

        }
    }
}
```

And I'm adding that custom view to an stack view in TicketDetailViewController dinamically, but I don't know how to resize the custom view according its self size:

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using CoreGraphics;

namespace Project.iOS
{
    public partial class TicketDetailViewController : UIViewController
    {
        private nfloat TicketItemHeight = 200;
        TicketModel _ticketItem;
        List<TicketCommentModel> _ticketCommentsList;
        TicketDetailPresenter _presenter;

        public TicketDetailViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            _presenter = new TicketDetailPresenter(this);
        }

        public async override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            ScrollView.LoadingStart();
            await _presenter.LoadTicketComments(_ticketItem.Id);
            FillComentsStackView();
            ScrollView.LoadingComplete();
        }

        public void LoadMenuItem(TicketModel ticketItem)
        {
            _ticketItem = ticketItem;
        }

        public void FillComentsStackView()
        {
            foreach (TicketCommentModel item in _ticketCommentsList)
            { 
                TicketCommentRowUIView itemView = TicketCommentRowUIView.CreateView(item);
                itemView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(TicketItemHeight).Active = true;
                CommentStackView.AddArrangedSubview(itemView);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

My issue is that I don't know how to add an self size for each custom view, because the height of MessageReply UILabel it is variable... I put a constraint equals to 200 but when the text is too big it looks overlapped. And when it is a short text there is to much of blank space. Is there any way to do this?? In my android project I just set WrapContent layout params and it worked. But I can't find the way to apply that to the iOS project. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have set the Label's Line 0 to wrap its content.

Then you can set each item's constraint in your xib to make your custom view self size fit. From your screenshot you can set the left, top constraint of your image and top, left constraint of your `DateReply`, at last the left, top, right , bottom constraint of the `MessageReply` like: [image]

Adjust the constant to feed your request. Moreover when you add the custom view in the `TicketDetailViewController`, there's no need to set the `HeightAnchor`.